My axis are going crazy + my grab tool wont work?
Something is up with my axis, it doesn't usually look like this, and I don't know how to fix it.
I tried to add a new object and grab it ,and it didn't even budge.
What's going on? How do I restore everything back to normal?


Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

Check if you have "only origins" selected in the options:

By default, there should be none of those options selected.

Thanks, Lauloque you've been a great help! My 'orgins' and 'locations' were both ticked.  Once I un-clicked them, things seem to have gone back to normal. I can now grab and move my objects freely again.

@MickeyMouse,  Welcome
